# How can i get the bottom tabs size in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using the react-native-navigation library, and i need to get bottom tabs width, is there any api for react-native?

Comment: [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) by WIX or [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) ?

Comment: [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) by wix

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.